# Common Header Ui in swagger api documentation in .net core

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-2.2

What I need basically is a common header passing parameter like the authorization which will send same static value each time in header once added (this value can also be null in my case)

[image]

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "SomeTitle", Version = "v1" });
            c.OperationFilter<CustomHeaderSwaggerAttribute>();
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Description = "Please insert JWT with Bearer into field",
                Name = "Authorization",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
            });

            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Name = "Bearer",
                        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "Bearer"
                        },
                     },
                     new string[] {}
                 }
            });

        });
```

This is my configuration code in which I've currently implemented the CustomHeaderSwaggerAttribute. That is used to get the custom header with every request individually like the picture attached below
[image]